# Is it possible to inject a value from the named channel configuration property in spring-cloud-stream?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a spring-cloud-stream-kafka project. The following is an abbreviated section of application.yaml. I am interested in injecting the value for the property `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.myNamedChannel.dlqPartitions` into code:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:        
      kafka:
        bindings:
          myNamedChannel-in-0:
            consumer:
              start-offset: earliest
              enable-dlq: true
              dlq-partitions: 4
              dlq-name: myNamedChannel-dlt
```

I have tried permutations on the following without any success. Is something like this possible?

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.myNamedChannel.consumer.dlqPartitions}")
private int CONTEXT_RETRY_PARTITION_COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. This works:

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.myNamedChannel-in-0.consumer.dlq-partitions}")
private int CONTEXT_RETRY_PARTITION_COUNT;
```